# Strange issue with System.Web.Mvc losing its reference when checking out of TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013, .net-assembly

I'm working with another developer on a project and everything has been working great until today.  Now when I check out the solution to my Visual studio 2013, my reference to System.Web.Mvc is lost and I have to manually re-add it.

When I check in and she checks out, the same issue occurs for her.  The path to the assembly is the same on both of our machines:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET MVC
>   4\Assemblies\System.Web.Mvc.dll

but for whatever reason, we're not in sync.  As I said above, it was working great until today so something must've changed...but I have no idea what???

Any suggestions/ideas of what to look for to resolve this?

TIA

Comment: You mentioned TFS. If you're saying that it was working perfectly fine yesterday but not today. Can't you go through the previous versions/revisions/changesets and compare it with the current version and see what changed?

Comment: turns out MS did a security update last night and her machine didn't update yet.  Their security update specifically addresses the mvc assembly: https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/MS14-059.  I guess a lot of people have had this issue today :(

Comment: This means both of your machines have the dll file but there's some kind of version conflict as you have updated and she didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurred due to a Security update that incremented the version of MVC. So if you had References in your project pointing to the hard drive where the 2.0/ 3.0/ 4.0 version was. Your project was needing that particular version. Another way to solve this is to use Nuget to update references.

This is a post from Microsoft regarding the issue:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/microsoft-asp-net-mvc-security-update-broke-my-build.aspx

Comment: This issue occurred due to a Security update that incremented the version of MVC.  So if you had References in your project pointing to the hard drive where the 2.0/ 3.0/ 4.0 version was.  Your project was needing that particular version.  Another way to solve this is to use Nuget to update references.